# puppet rspec not working on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rspec, puppet

I have no prior experience at all of ruby.  I am not interested in ruby (and so have no knowledge of rails etc) as such but am using puppet to manage a group of servers.  I have written some modules and the rspec-puppet system looks like it would be very useful.

However, I cannot get rspec-puppet to work

I am using Ubuntu LTS 10.04

I have installed puppet rspec using the directions on their web page

What I actually did

```
apt-get install rubygems # (installs 1.8)
gem install rspec-expectations
gem install rspec-puppet
```

I also installed librspec-ruby1.8

Then I ran rspec-puppet-init in a puppet module directory I'd already made (it's a working puppet module)

I made a file as defined in the tutorial

```
$ more spec/defines/rule_spec.rb 
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'vanusers::rule' do
let(:title) { 't1' }

it { should contain_class('vanusers::JamieA') }
end
```

but when I try and run it there is a mysterious dependancy issue

```
$ spec spec/defines/rule_spec.rb 
/home/jamie/git/puppet/modules/vanusers/spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rspec-puppet (LoadError)
    from /home/jamie/git/puppet/modules/vanusers/spec/spec_helper.rb:1
    from ./spec/defines/rule_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from ./spec/defines/rule_spec.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/options.rb:132:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/spec:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spec_helper` is a include file that needs to be present in `spec/spec_helper.rb`. It typically includes all related ruby gems that are required for test functionality.

You should look at the manual setup guide - in particular the spec_helper part: http://rspec-puppet.com/setup/

Comment: As you can see from the traceback, the ``spec/spec_helper.rb`` file is already being found, it exists and was made by ``rspec-puppet-init``.  I did eventually find a fix for the problem (thanks to @Volcane on #puppet freenode irc) and that was to add ``require 'rubygems'`` at the start of the spec_helper.rb file.  Given you an up vote / accept for the suggestion to look at the manual setup docs